# Can I copy the text in an iPhone notification and send to telegram channel?

Tags: ios, notifications, telegram

I’m getting trading signals on my iPhone via an app which sends the signals as a notification. Can that notification information be copied and sent to my telegram account? I have a telegram to MT4 program running but am currently having to type in the information. I’m trying to fully automate the process.